# How do the "anchor" trading ports work?

Tags: shogun-2-total-war

On the left (south?) of the map there are a collection of foreign trading "anchors".  You can put a trading (or any fleet vessel) there.  Presumably this is a good thing somehow.

1. Where can I see the value of having the trading ship there in my finances?
2. Do I need to keep a trading ship there all the time, or can it wander off immediately the port is captured?
3. Is there any value in putting more ships there?
4. Does it need to be a 'trading ship' to start the trade, or can any vessel go there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You can place up to 10 ships in 1 fleet
- You can put 1 fleet into a trading port
- For each **trading ship** (war ships have no effect here) in a fleet occupying a trading port, you get a certain amount of money each turn.
- The amount you get is calculated every turn, so if you remove a trading ship from that fleet, you will earn less money next turn from that trading port
- If you put at least 1 trading ship on an trading port, a trading route will appear between that trading port and one of your coastal cities.
- IIRC, you can check the amount of money from a trading route simply by hovering your mouse over it.
- You can see last turn's total trading route revenue in the balance sheet.

The best strategy to maximize revenue from an trading port is to put a fleet of 10 trading ships there and park some escorting warships directly next to it. The zone of control from the warships do not prevent enemies from attacking your trade fleet, but they will join the battle.

Answer (score 0):

Bring a Trade ship or an European trade ship (or more) on that post.You will get resources that you can trade with others and use them for yourself.